# sass using variable as mixin data

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm using grid from csswizardry and wanting to create breakpoints as variables...
If defined as standard "strings":

```
$breakpoints: (
    'palm' '(max-width: 480px)'
)!default;
```

But when I change it to:

```
$palmmaxwidth: 480px;
$breakpoints: (
    'palm' '(max-width: $palmmaxwidth)'
)!default;
```

it will not compile correctly within the mixin:

```
@mixin grid-media-query($media-query){
    $breakpoint-found: false;

    @each $breakpoint in $breakpoints{
        $name: nth($breakpoint, 1);
        $declaration: nth($breakpoint, 2);

        @if $media-query == $name and $declaration{
            $breakpoint-found: true;

            @media only screen and #{$declaration}{
                @content;
            }
        }
    }

    @if $breakpoint-found == false{
        @warn "Breakpoint ‘#{$media-query}’ does not exist"
    }
}
```

The error is `Invalid CSS after "...nd (max-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "$palmmaxwidth)"`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple after trying every possible combination:

```
$breakpoints: (
    'palm' '(max-width: '+$palmmaxwidth+')'
)!default;
```

Comment: you could also use string interpolation `'(max-width: #{$palmmaxwidth})'` instead of concatenation